# how to adjust/control picture size on tkinter python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

how do i adjust the size of image? Thanks

```
canvas = Canvas(width = 300, height = 200, bg = 'white')
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky = 'W')
gif = PhotoImage(file = "picture.gif")
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = gif, anchor = NW)
mainloop()
```